# PHP session variables are not saved when using fetch API

Tags: javascript, php

So I set session variables in one php file

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
  $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
```

And then I'm trying to access those values in another php file

```
  session_start();
  session_regenerate_id();
  var_dump($_SESSION);
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || !isset($_SESSION['role'])) {
    header(':', true, 401);
    exit;
  }
```

When printing out right after setting them, the values look fine, however in the first snippet var_dump returns that $_SESSION is empty. I'm thinking that it might be javascript (or fetch API to be more specific) problem as when I'm using postman to handle those requests, all the values are being saved just fine. I've tried using ajax but the problem still remained.

Comment: what is your fetch code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because PHP doesn't know about your current session. PHP sessions are usually tracked by placing a cookie with the session id in it and then read from the cookie upon a request being made to the script. But, the Fetch api does not send cookies by default with requests.

> https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode
>
> A request has an associated credentials mode, which is "omit",
>   "same-origin", or "include". **Unless stated otherwise, it is "omit"**.

So you need to set the Request credentials property to `same-origin` or `include`

same-orign - Only include credentials, like cookies, for requests to same-orign domains

include    - Always send credentials

```
fetch("/url/endpoint",{
  credentials:"same-origin"
})
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Are there issues with path perhaps? I've path `'/'` in init.php where session is created and this file is included in normal flow as well as in /app/api/called-with-fetch-api.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to set credentials to 'include' when making the fetch request.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#sending_credentials_with_a_fetch_request

```
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'
})
```